# Reserved workers for each virtualhost for Apache prefork

Tags: performance, apache, virtualhost

I am supervising the Apache prefork server on Cent OS.
Apache hosts several ASP.NET Core services using proxy.
Usually apache serves 20 requests per second and server limit is 920 workers.
In case of busyness of one hosted service, incomming requests occupy all apache workers very fast.
In consequence of this, a request that are dedicated for another service i.e. virtualhost has no free worker.

Is it possible to reserve defined amount of workers for specific virtualhost?

Something like this:

```
subdomain1.myserver.com:443 - 200 Workers
subdomain2.myserver.com:443 - 200 Workers
subdomain3.myserver.com:443 - 200 Workers
subdomain4.myserver.com:443 - 200 Workers
myserver.com:4800 - 70 Workers
myserver.com:443 - 50 Workers
```

Thank you